# Repeating phrases like "There are questions after questions after…"

Tags: repetition

What is the correct way of punctuating repeating phrases in a sentence?  Are commas and semicolons required?

Example:

**"There are questions after questions after questions after questions on page after page."**

BTW, let's assume the extra repetitions are necessary.

Answer (score 4):

No, you usually wouldn't use any sort of punctuation in a construction like that.

> You give me assignment after assignment after assignment. I can't handle all this stress!

That being said, you usually wouldn't go past three repetitions. "Question after question after question after question" starts to get a bit awkward.

Comment: Gertrude Stein agrees with you

Comment: I looked her up, and I can't see how that's relevant.

Comment: "Rose is a rose is a rose is a rose"

Comment: I see. Never heard of that quote before.